# How to implement a multiple comparisons unpaired t-test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, multiple-comparisons

Suppose I have the following data set break down:

Group A: subjects $A_1$, $A_2$, $A_3$, and $A_4$

Condition 1, Condition 2, Condition 3

All four subjects have a corresponding value for each condition:

$\{A_1^1, A_2^1, A_3^1, A_4^1\}$

$\{A_1^2, A_2^2, A_3^2, A_4^2\}$

$\{A_1^3, A_2^3, A_3^3, A_4^3\}$

Therefore we have three means for these collections, respectively: $\mu_A^1$, $\mu_A^2$, and $\mu_A^3$

Group B: subjects $B_1$, $B_2$, $B_3$, and $B_4$

Condition 1, Condition 2, Condition 3

All four subjects have a corresponding value for each condition:

$\{B_1^1, B_2^1, B_3^1, B_4^1\}$

$\{B_1^2, B_2^2, B_3^2, B_4^2\}$

$\{B_1^3, B_2^3, B_3^3, B_4^3\}$

Therefore we have three means for these collections, respectively: $\mu_B^1$, $\mu_B^2$, and $\mu_B^3$.

---

The hypothesis that I would like to test for is: $\mu_A^1 \gt \mu_B^1 \text{ and }\mu_A^2 \gt \mu_B^2 \text{ and }\mu_A^3 \gt \mu_B^3$.

i.e. I want to know if all three of these relationships are simultaneously satisfied.

I believe this is described as a *multiple unpaired t-test*.

If any one could please provide me with a basic understanding of how to proceed, I would greatly appreciate it! Cheers~

Comment: Do you believe the values of each condition are correlated for each person. Ex: If $A_{1}^{1}$ is large, do you expect $A_{1}^{2}$, $A_{1}^{3}$, and $A_{1}^{4}$ to be large as well? The alternative is that the four conditions are independent from one another.

Comment: @Eli For my particular data set, yes, I suspect that there are correlations across the conditions within a particular subject. If possible, I would like to consider both possibilities, though.

Comment: I do not believe you are interested in multiple comparison t-testing, otherwise referred to as pairwise t-testing. I say this because you are making three independent comparisons: 1>1 and 2>2 and 3>3.  Correct? Meaning, you are not interested in comparing 1A to 2B? The question of paired or unpaired is only related to whether the subject from group 1A is the same as 1B, if it is, the test is paired.  If it's two different subjects, then it's unpaired.  If you use R, I will post a code for the answer. Let me know if this is correct what I stated above

Comment: @Andy I'm not sure I fully understand your comments, but it is true that subjects $A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4, B_1, B_2, B_3, B_4$ are all different subjects.

Comment: @S.Cramer: Ok, so this is for sure an unpaired test.  Next, to clarify, you are only interested in comparing 1 to 1, correct?  You are not interested in comparing 1 to 2,3, & 4. If this statement is correct, I count a total of 4 individual unpaired t-tests you can perfrom.  If this is the case, I will post an answer (using R code language, if that's ok with you) below.

Comment: @Andy I am fairly certain you need to account for the fact that there are multiple tests (i.e. the p-value needs to be adjusted). This is the purpose of the question - specifically, how does one analytically deduce the correction factor to the p-vale (given the conditions)

Comment: @S.Cramer I don't see anything about correction methods in the question? Unless there is pairwise testing, than of course you must do a correction.  But if he runs 4 individual test, and does not compare the tests between eachother, than it's for individual t-tests, no correction. Additionally, I have a post about bonferroni and holm if you are interested in seeing it, would be nice to hear your opinion on it:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/571126/verifying-holm-correction-line-on-fwer-graph

Comment: @Andy the fact that I want those 3 hypotheses to be simultaneously tested requires a multiple comparisons correction. I assume that the Bonferoni procedure may be all I need here to give me an adjusted p-value to use. At this point, I think I can do as you said and simply run individual t-tests using this adjusted p-value.